# How can I find my controls on the form in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a form which I have created in Visual Studio and there are some controls on there with strange names which have events associated with them.  I think the controls have been added in error.  They are labels.  I can't see them on the form, they must have no text or be behind something.  How can I find them?

Comment: What form are you using? Windows/WPF/Web forms?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline menu command.  You'll get a tool window that displays all the children of the form.  You can drag+drop a control up to its container to put it on top of the Z-order, in case such a label is covered by another control.  Or right-click a rogue one and select Delete.  Edit + Undo if you made a mistake.

Comment: Thats great thanks Hans.  It has allowed me to delete the rogue controls, and also to go through and check that all my controls have systematic/consistent names.

Comment: why this window isn't open by default? this is so handy!

Comment: That worked also for Visual Studio 2019 and a C++ project

Answer (score 0):

1. Display the Properties window.  (Use View, Properties Window if it is not already displayed.)
2. In the dropdown at the top of the Properties window, select the control that is giving you problems.
3. Change the Location to 0,0.
4. The control should now be at the top-left corner of your form, so that you can delete it.
5. If you can't see it, click in the white area outside of your form.  Then the Format menu will appear from which you can pick Order, Bring to Front.

Copied from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1bbde330-bd12-450e-8f56-af34a626ee13/can-not-find-hidden-control-in-form-designer?forum=winforms)